# Update successfully but couldn't update into DB

Tags: php, mysqli

I couldn't find any error. I tried the query on phpmyadmin and it works well but when I do in php page, it couldn't update into DB. The following code below:

```
$registerID = ($_POST['registerID']);
$firstName = ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']));
$lastName = ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastName']));
$emailAddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddress']);
$mainAddress = ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullAddress']));
$updateCity = ucwords($_POST['userCity']);
$updateCountry = $_POST['userCountry'];
$postalCode = strtoupper(htmlspecialchars($_POST['userZip']));
$profilePic = $_POST['pic'];

$updateProf = " UPDATE register_user
                SET firstName='$firstName',
                    lastName='$lastName',
                    emailAddress='$emailAddress',
                    mainAddress='$mainAddress',
                    registerCity='$updateCity',
                    registerCountry='$updateCountry',
                    postalCode='$postalCode'
                WHERE registerID = '$registerID'";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateProf)) {

        echo "Record updated successfully";

        } else {

        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

In the end, there are no errors after I updated on the webpage, it just show **Record updated successfully**. But it didn't update into DB. Any ideas?

**UPDATED CODING**

```
$checkProfile = "SELECT * FROM register_user where emailAddress = '$emailAddress'";
$editProfile = mysqli_query($mysqli,$checkProfile);

if ($editProfile) {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($editProfile) > 0) {

            header("Location: event?error=That name of email has already been taken");

            } else {

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE register_user
                    SET firstName = '$firstName',
                        lastName = '$lastName',
                        emailAddress = '$emailAddress',
                        mainAddress = '$mainAddress',
                        registerCity = '$updateCity',
                        registerCountry = '$updateCountry',
                        postalCode = '$postalCode'
                        WHERE registerID = '$registerID'";

            $updateResult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$updateQuery);

            header("Location: profileUser");

            }
}
```

After I updated, it still doesn't work after I am using prepared statement. Any ideas?

Comment: `it didn't insert into DB`? your doing an update, why should it insert?

Comment: Sorry, i meant update..

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think you're open to SQL injection with that query... Try to parametrise your query instead...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use prepared statements! Using htmlspecialchars in this context is pretty bad practice. Use it before you output the data, not when you store it!

Comment: @BreyndotEchse thank you for your suggestion, I shall using prepare statement to make it perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the query first, saving it into a variable.
then, check if the query executed by doing:

```
if(!$query) echo "Query error : " . $mysqli->error;
```

This will give you more detailed error report.

Comment: If you try to execute the query directly in phpmyadmin, using not variables but sample data, does it work?